# Checking each char in a string giving unexpected results

Tags: c, string, char, base64

I'm making a base64 encoder/decoder, I have a function to encode the input binary into its base64 representation. The input is a **string** of `0`'s and `1`'s.

My `if` statement is failing to validate that each `char` in the `string` is a '`0`' or '`1`'. It says that every `char` is not a '`0`' or '`1`'. Even though it is.

My code: (not the full functions code...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *enc(char *);

int main(void) 
{
    enc("1101010100100101001010010101001"); 
    return 0;
}

char *enc(const char *data)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++)
    {
        if(data[i] != '0' || data[i] != '1') 
        {
            printf("index %d is not 0 or 1\n", i);
            printf("instead it is: %c\n", data[i]);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This outputs that every `char` is **NOT** a `0` or `1`.

IDEone: http://ideone.com/0MqNN4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(data[i] != '0' || data[i] != '1')
```

If char is not 0 *or* char is not 1 -> always true. I think you meant *and*:

```
if(data[i] != '0' && data[i] != '1')
```

"not a or b" in English translates to "not (a or b)" in boolean logic, which by De Morgan's Laws, is equivalent to "(not a) and (not b)".

Comment: Based on the `printf` statement, I understood you were checking to ensure that `data[i]` was neither 0 or 1 (in order to print an error message), which translates to `(not 0) and (not 1)`. If instead, you want to check that `data[i]` is either 0 or 1, you should use `data[i] == 0 || data[i] == 1`

Comment: Yes that is correct, otherwise the input would be malformed. I've tried the `&&` method in IDEone and it works. Ninja edit.

Comment: That was an error on my half, it did work but the `stdout` didn't clear when I re-ran the program so I thought it gave the same output!

Answer (score 0):

put `&&` operator for checking  `if(data[i]!= '0' && data[i]!= '1')`